# Why does applying this Galois automorphism $\sigma$ to each entry of a matrix representation $\varphi\colon G\to GL_n(F)$ preserve irreducibility?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $F\subset\mathbb{C}$ by the subfield of algebraic numbers, and let $\varphi\colon G\to GL_n(F)$ be a representation of a finite group $G$, with character $\psi$.

Let $\mathbb{Q}(\varphi)$ denote the subfield of $F$ generated by adjoining the entries $\varphi(g)$ for all $g\in G$. Since this amounts to adjoining finitely many algebraic elements of finite degree, $\mathbb{Q}(\varphi)/\mathbb{Q}$ is finite.

Now let $K$ be a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ containing $\mathbb{Q}(\varphi)$. For $\sigma\in\operatorname{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$, $\sigma$ extends to an automorphism of $F$, also denoted $\sigma$, and then we can define $\varphi^\sigma\colon G\to GL_n(F)$ by setting $\varphi^\sigma(g)$ to be the matrix $\varphi(g)$ with $\sigma$ applied to each entry. I was able to show that $\varphi^\sigma$ is a representation, and that the character of $\varphi^\sigma$ is $\sigma\circ\psi$.

> Why is $\varphi$ irreducible if and only if $\varphi^\sigma$ is irreducible?

I know that a character is irreducible iff it has norm $1$, so I think it would be enough to show $\psi$ has norm $1$ iff $\sigma\circ\psi$ has norm $1$. Since the norm has formala
$$
\|\psi\|^2=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_i |C(g_i)||\psi(g_i)|^2
$$

where the sum is over a set of representatives $g_i$ of each conjugacy class $C(g_i)$, it would even be enough to show $\psi$ and $\sigma\circ\psi$ have the same norm on an arbitrary conjugacy class, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Is there a way to possibly show that $K$ contains the cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$? I know that each $\varphi(g)$ is diagonalizable to a matrix whose diagonal consists of $n$th roots of unity. Then $K$ would be a Galois extension containing $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$, so its Galois group would be contained in the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$. Since every cyclotomic automorphism commutes with complex conjugation, I think this would imply $\sigma$ commutes with complex conjugation, and with that I could directly compute $\|\sigma\circ\psi\|$.
Thanks.

This discussion is essentially 18.3.14-17 of Dummit and Foote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, note that we only have to show that if $\varphi$ is not irreducible, then $\varphi^\sigma$ is not irreducible either (the other direction follows then from $(\varphi^{\sigma})^{\sigma^{-1}} = \varphi$).

If $\varphi$ is not irreducible, it admits a nontrivial subrepresentation $\varphi'$ and we find a matrix $A\in GL_n(F)$ such that $$A \varphi(g)A^{-1} = \pmatrix{\varphi'(g) & * \\ 0 & \varphi''(g)}$$ for all $g$. 
Because $\sigma$ is a ring automorphism we find that 
$$A^{\sigma} \varphi^{\sigma}(g){A^{\sigma}}^{-1} = (A \varphi(g)A^{-1})^{\sigma} = \pmatrix{\varphi'^\sigma(g) & * \\ 0 & \varphi''^\sigma(g)}$$ for all $g$, that is, $\varphi^{\sigma}$ has the nontrivial subrepresentation $\varphi'^\sigma$ and is thus not irreducible.

Comment: By the asterisk in the matrices, you actually mean the zero block matrices right?

Comment: @Bach: a representation is not simple if there exists a proper non-trivial invariant subspace. Extending a basis of this invariant subspace to the whole space and applying the base change $A$, this will give you a block upper triangular matrix as I described. Conversely, given a representation in this form the first few (standard) basis vectors give the desired invariant subspace. In characteristic zero, all representations of finite groups are completely reducible, so that you can replace the asterisks by zero blocks, but to answer the question this additional knowledge is not required.

Comment: You are right. Thank you!